# Location proximity search using API

Tags: 7, location

I have a small number of location nodes with geofields, and need to programmatically get the distance between a location and a zip code.  It would be ideal if I could get a query, or a sort, of my location nodes by proximity to the zip code.  I couldn't easily tell how to do this in the geoPHP module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short : Use the Location Distance field in Views.

In detail : Check out the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxeskzN8BAc

Comment: The Location module has all the code in there.  Thanks!